# Что делает данный код (Си)?

Tags: linux, c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    char buf[40];
    puts("Welcome to hxp's Echo Service!");
    while (1)
    {
        printf("> ");
        ssize_t len = read(0, buf, 0x60);
        if (len <= 0) return 0;
        if (buf[len - 1] == '\n') buf[--len] = 0;
        if (len == 0) return 0;
        puts(buf);
    }
}
const void* foo = system;
```

В одной директории с этим-же кодом есть файл без расширения.

Comment: С точки зрения языка С код не делает ничего определенного - код некорректен из-за `const void* foo = system;`. Если вопрос о поведении в каком-то С-подобном языке, то указывайте компилятор и, желательно, его настройки.

Comment: Отключает буферизацию для stdin/stdout и копирует stdin в stdout. Завершается по вводу пустой строки. Меня только смущает, что в принципе он может прочесть с переполнением буфера (0x60 == 96 > 40). Возможно это exploit, который при определенном вводе вызовет [system](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)